# How to find domain and codomain?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be given by $g(x)=|x|^2$.

Find the domain and codomain for derivative map $Dg$.

Not really sure as where to start? Also, sorry about the text, I hope that its understandable, or that maybe someone could edit it for me? Not really good with technology.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that by $Dg$ you mean the *gradient* / *total differential* of $g$. If that's not what you mean, let me know in comments.

Observe that for $x  = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$ we have $g(x) = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2$. It follows that $Dg(x) =(2x_1, \ldots , 2x_n)$.
The domain is clearly all of $\mathbb{R^n}$, since $Dg$ is defined everywhere. Since $Dg$ maps values from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$, the codomain is simply that: $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Besides, for $y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ we have $Dg(\frac{y}{2}) = y$, thus the image is also all of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: Your co-domain is wrong because your formula for $Dg$ is wrong. $g'=(2x_1,\ldots,2x_n)$ but $Dg=g'h$ where $h$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so the co-domain is just $\mathbb{R}$. See Spivak calculus on manifolds.

Comment: @AnonymousStudent I believe the notation is not consistent. The way a learned it, $Dg$ is essentially the gradient of $g$ in this case. I edited my answer for clarification.